# Keeping creeping thyme, or other ground cover, weed free (aka thyme vs. clover)

Tags: weed-control, ground-cover

I have a path with flagstone, with the gap between the stones being around an inch or so.  I've had creeping thyme growing between the stones, but it's been a huge battle keeping other plants, specifically clover (which I think may have already been living in the thyme plants when I brought them home from the nursery).  I've spent quite a bit of time pulling up the invaders and as much of their roots as possible, but it's been a very time-consuming process.  I'm worried that the clover might crowd out the thyme, which hasn't always been as hardy as I'd like.

Anyone have any pointers on maintaining healthy, mostly weed free ground covers, especially gap-filling plants?  Any hints on blocking or retarding the growth of invaders?  Or should I give up on this plant and try to find something that's going to grow more aggressively in this space (clover seems to like this location)?

Also, I'd prefer to stick to an organic solution and not use any harsh chemicals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're aiming for uniformity, and you don't mind the look of the clover, I'd say just let the clover take over. My experiences with white clover are that it is capable of choking out pretty much everything else. It would provide a nice, low, green appearance to your path.

Answer (score 2):

There is no permanent solution to keep creeping thyme weed free.
You can use a pre-emergent (like Preen) to hinder germination- which will help a lot- but there will still be some weeds. Pre-emergents do not kill plants but hinder seeds from germinating.